# Running cruise control as service in cruise control version 1.6.7981.1

Tags: cruisecontrol

I am trying to run cruise control as service but it is opening ccservice.exe window while starting the service in cruise control version 1.6.7981.1. It is not opening ccservice.exe window with older version of ccnet. Is it the feature of this version or we have to do some thing more to disappear that window?

Answer (score 0):

you have two possibilities:
run ccnet directly on console mode
run ccnet from services.msc to launch windows service